# Excel DataFlow UML Viewer/Navigator/Visualiser tool/ hint

Tags: microsoft-excel, uml

Not sure what to call it but, is there a birds eye view tool for excel to show the data flow between excel sheets/cels etc? I have inherited some huge reports and looking at each cell to see where it's data comes from or what sheet/cell dependencies it has is a nightmare.

Or even just something with excel that show the dependencies within a sheet of cells to each other etc.

Or Any other visualization tool that can show the data flow between cells ( I tried visio but it seemed it is only for making diagrams of data not the data model of excel itself ).

Or at least if I am within a cell and see a formula referring to other sheets and cells, is there a quick way to navigate there and back? Like code navigation in VS?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2004 you can trace predecessors etc by selecting a cell then Tools->Auditing->Trace Precedents.

The menu option might differ in other versions of Excel but has been there in other versions. Also in the extras there might be some more auditing functions.

Comment: Thank you, Auditing tools in Excel 2007, on the formulas tab,
I can't up vote you cause I don't have enough reputation, but I'll be back.